# Can't set native resolution for ultrawide monitor

Tags: drivers, 20.04, display-resolution

Resolution I have in Windows is 2560x1080, but in Ubuntu maximum is 1920x1080. Things I tried:

- added custom resolution, but it just shows blank screen and reverts back to original
- set different Hz, no luck
- tried to install drivers from AMD, but seems they're outdated
- in "Additional Drivers" ATI Driver sometimes shows up, sometime doesn't. Had 2 options there, tried both, no luck
- custom resolution works on laptop screen, but on external display shows only  blank screen when trying to apply new resolution

OS: Ubuntu 20.04, Graphics card: ATI Mobility Radeon 5870 HD

[---> xrandr output <---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzPQJ.png)

Comment: Run `xrandr` and update Your question with the output.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Thanks for pointing out. Updated.

Comment: What monitor do You have? Do You use hdmi or displayport? Does Your monitor support this resolution via hdmi?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Monitor: LG 34UM68-P, Port: HDMI, Supports resolution via hdmi: yes, i'm using it on Windows in native resolution (2560x1080) without any issues